# Missing } when using \begin{align*}

Tags: errors, align

I have scoured my code and tried it out without the alignment. There is nothing i can see wrong with the code, but when I try to use align or eqnarray, I always get some error message. Here's the code

```
\begin{align*}  
\oint_{|\zeta| &= \hat{R_2}} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z} d\zeta \\ 
           &= \oint \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{z}{\zeta}}    
d\zeta\\             
&= \oint \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{z}  
{\zeta}} d\zeta \\      
&= \oint \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta} \cdot \left( 1 +   
\frac{z}{\zeta} + \frac{z^2}{\zeta^2} + \cdots \right)  d\zeta \\
&= \oint \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta} d\zeta + \oint \frac{f(\zeta)} 
{\zeta^2} z d\zeta + \oint \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^3} z^2 d\zeta
%
\end{align*}
```

And here's the error message:

```
home/username/Dropbox/Math 132/.2013-07-01.tex.swp:105: Missing } inserted.   

<inserted text> 
            }  
l.105 \end{align*}
```

/home/username/Dropbox/Math 132/.2013-07-01.tex.swp:105:  ==> Fatal error occurred,

Thank you !

Comment: You have a `&` in the subscript of `\oint`. That doesn’t belong there.

Answer (score 3):

your first line should be:

```
\oint_{|\zeta|} &= \hat{R_2} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z} d\zeta \\
```

and maybe that `\oint\limits_` looks nicer

Comment: So the missing } was at the beginning, good catch and thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

  \begin{document}
   \begin{align*}  
      \oint_{|\zeta|} &= \hat{R_2} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z} d\zeta \\ 
                        &= \oint \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{z}{\zeta}}  d\zeta\\             
                        &= \oint \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{z} {\zeta}} d\zeta \\      
                        &= \oint \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta} \cdot \left( 1 + \frac{z}{\zeta} + \frac{z^2}{\zeta^2} + \cdots \right)  d\zeta \\
                        &= \oint \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta} d\zeta + \oint \frac{f(\zeta)} {\zeta^2} z d\zeta + \oint \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^3} z^2 d\zeta
   \end{align*}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post only code without any explaining text.